Solving vector equations in $ℝ^3$
I've recently been trying to solve the following problems in the unknown vector $\vec{r}$ given non coplanar vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$;
(i) $\vec{a} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{b})\times\vec{a}]+\vec{b} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{c})\times\vec{b}]+\vec{c} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{a})\times\vec{c}]=0$
(ii) $\vec{r} \times \vec{a}+(\vec{r}.\vec{b})\vec{c}=\vec{b} \times \vec{c}$ and it is given that $\vec{a}.\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a}.\vec{c}$ are nonzero
(iii)This one is the most difficult of them all in two simultaneous equations in two unknown vectors $\vec{r_1},\vec{r_2}$;
$\vec{r_1}+\vec{c} \times \vec{r_2}=\vec{a}$ and $\vec{r_2}+\vec{c} \times \vec{r_1}=\vec{b}$.
The only method of solving vector equations that I know is to express $\vec{r}=x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}+z\vec{c}$ and then solve for $x,y,z$ by setting the coefficients of $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ equal to $0$. While theoretically, this may seem sound, in practice, it is usually quite time-consuming, computationally inefficient, not at all insightful into the geometry of the unknown vector until you have analytically found it completely, and it doesn't even work in the third problem at all! Also, using this method, I'm unable to exploit the cyclicity or simplicity of these equations.
I'm looking for a solution that relies more heavily on $3D$ geometric insights, or performing simple manipulations like taking dot product or cross product on both sides to eliminate something, etc but not anything that involves heavy use of linear algebra (I only know the basics). If you could share some tips and common strategies to solve vector equations in $ℝ^3$, that would be very helpful.
EDIT: The answers are given in the form of dot products, cross products (and triple products) of $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ so if possible, a method of solution which obtains the answer in this form directly, instead of in the components of $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$, would be appreciated!
Answers are given as follows;
(i) $ \vec{r}=\dfrac{\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}}{2}$
(ii) $\vec{r}=\dfrac{(\vec{a}  \times \vec{b}) . \vec{c}}{(\vec{a}.\vec{c})(\vec{a}.\vec{b})}(\vec{a}-\vec{b} \times \vec{c})+\dfrac{\vec{b} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{c})}{\vec{a}.\vec{b}} $
(iii) $\vec{r_1}=\dfrac{\vec{a}+(\vec{c}.\vec{a})\vec{c}+\vec{b} \times \vec{c}}{1+|\vec{c}|^2}$ and $\vec{r_2}=\dfrac{\vec{b}+(\vec{b}.\vec{c})\vec{c}-\vec{c} \times \vec{a}}{1+|\vec{c}|^2}$

For (iii) you  need to do $c\times$ and $c\cdot$ to each of the two given equations and expand the triple vector/scalar products in usual way; it's very straightforward.

Yeah, that works wonders, I don't know why I missed such a clean way to solve the third problem.

(i)
We can write
$$\vec{a} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{b})\times\vec{a}]=|\vec a|^2\vec r-(\vec a\cdot\vec r)\vec a-|\vec a|^2\vec b+(\vec a\cdot\vec b)\vec a$$
$$\vec{b} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{c})\times\vec{b}]=|\vec b|^2\vec r-(\vec b\cdot\vec r)\vec b-|\vec b|^2\vec c+(\vec b\cdot\vec c)\vec b$$
$$\vec{c} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{a})\times\vec{c}]=|\vec c|^2\vec r-(\vec c\cdot\vec r)\vec c-|\vec c|^2\vec a+(\vec c\cdot\vec a)\vec c$$
So, we have
$$\vec r=\frac{(\vec a\cdot\vec r)\vec a+(\vec b\cdot\vec r)\vec b+(\vec c\cdot\vec r)\vec c+\vec d}{|\vec a|^2+|\vec b|^2+|\vec c|^2}$$
where $$\vec d=|\vec c|^2\vec a+|\vec a|^2\vec b+|\vec b|^2\vec c-(\vec a\cdot\vec b)\vec a-(\vec b\cdot\vec c)\vec b-(\vec c\cdot\vec a)\vec c$$
By doing $\vec a\cdot$, we have
$$(|\vec b|^2+|\vec c|^2)(\vec a\cdot\vec r)-(\vec a\cdot\vec b)(\vec b\cdot\vec r)-(\vec a\cdot\vec c)(\vec c\cdot\vec r)-|\vec b|^2(\vec a\cdot\vec c)+(\vec b\cdot\vec c)(\vec a\cdot\vec b)-|\vec c|^2|\vec a|^2+(\vec c\cdot\vec a)^2=0\tag1$$
By doing $\vec b\cdot$, we have
$$(|\vec a|^2+|\vec c|^2)(\vec b\cdot\vec r)-(\vec b\cdot\vec a)(\vec a\cdot\vec r)-(\vec b\cdot\vec c)(\vec c\cdot\vec r)-|\vec a|^2|\vec b|^2+(\vec a\cdot\vec b)^2-|\vec c|^2(\vec b\cdot\vec a)+(\vec c\cdot\vec a)(\vec b\cdot\vec c)=0\tag2$$
By doing $\vec c\cdot$, we have
$$(|\vec a|^2+|\vec b|^2)(\vec c\cdot\vec r)-(\vec c\cdot\vec a)(\vec a\cdot\vec r)-(\vec c\cdot\vec b)(\vec b\cdot\vec r)-|\vec a|^2(\vec c\cdot\vec b)+(\vec a\cdot\vec b)(\vec c\cdot\vec a)-|\vec b|^2|\vec c|^2+(\vec b\cdot\vec c)^2=0\tag3$$
Solving the system $(1)(2)(3)$ for $\vec a\cdot\vec r, \vec b\cdot\vec r$ and $\vec c\cdot\vec r$, we can finally get $\vec r$.
(If I find a better idea, I will add it.)

(ii)
There is a simple solution.
By doing $\vec a\cdot$, we have
$$\vec{r}\cdot\vec{b}=\frac{\vec a\cdot(\vec{b} \times \vec{c})}{\vec a\cdot\vec{c}}$$
By doing $\vec b\times$, we have
$$\vec b\times(\vec r\times\vec a)+(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{b})(\vec b\times\vec{c})=\vec b\times(\vec{b} \times \vec{c})$$
i.e.
$$(\vec b\cdot\vec a)\vec r-(\vec b\cdot \vec r)\vec a+(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{b})(\vec b\times\vec{c})=\vec b\times(\vec{b} \times \vec{c})$$
i.e.
$$(\vec b\cdot\vec a)\vec r=\vec b\times(\vec{b} \times \vec{c})+(\vec b\cdot \vec r)(\vec a-\vec b\times\vec{c})$$
So, we finally have
$$\vec r=\frac{\vec b\times(\vec{b} \times \vec{c})+\frac{\vec a\cdot(\vec{b} \times \vec{c})}{\vec a\cdot\vec{c}}(\vec a-\vec b\times\vec{c})}{\vec b\cdot\vec a}$$

(iii)
The comment by ancient mathematician is very helpful.
By doing $\vec c\cdot $, we have
$$\vec c\cdot\vec{r_1}=\vec c\cdot\vec{a}$$
$$\vec c\cdot \vec{r_2}=\vec c\cdot\vec{b}$$
By doing $\vec c\times $, we have
$$\vec c\times\vec{r_1}+\vec c\times (\vec{c} \times \vec{r_2})=\vec c\times\vec{a}$$
i.e.
$$\vec c\times\vec{r_1}+(\vec c\cdot\vec{r_2})\vec c-|\vec c|^2\vec{r_2}=\vec c\times\vec{a}$$
i.e.
$$\vec b-\vec{r_2}+(\vec c\cdot\vec{b})\vec c-|\vec c|^2\vec{r_2}=\vec c\times\vec{a}$$
i.e.
$$\vec{r_2}=\dfrac{\vec{b}+(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c})\vec{c}-\vec{c} \times \vec{a}}{1+|\vec{c}|^2}$$
Similarly, $$\vec{r_1}=\dfrac{\vec{a}+(\vec{c}\cdot\vec{a})\vec{c}-\vec{b} \times \vec{c}}{1+|\vec{c}|^2}$$

(i) The provided answer is wrong. For instance, if $\vec{a}=(1,1,0)$, $\vec{b}=(0,1,0)$, $\vec{c}=(0,0,1)$, and $\vec{r}=\frac{\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}}2=(1/2,1,1/2)$ then Mathcad yields
$$\vec{a} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{b})\times\vec{a}]+\vec{b} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{c})\times\vec{b}]+\vec{c} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{a})\times\vec{c}]=(1/2,-1/2,1/2)\ne 0.$$

The only method of solving vector equations that I know is to express $\vec{r}=x\vec{a}+y\vec{b}+z\vec{c}$ and then solve for $x,y,z$ by setting the coefficients of $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ equal to $0$.

It is natural to apply this method. Then
$$\vec{a} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{b})\times\vec{a}]=$$
$$\vec{a} \times[[x\vec{a}+(y-1)\vec{b}+z\vec{c})]\times\vec{a}]=$$
$$\vec{a} \times[(y-1)\vec{b}\times\vec{a}+z\vec{c}\times\vec{a})]=$$
$$(y-1)\vec{a}\times[\vec{b}\times\vec{a}]+z\vec{a}\times[\vec{c}\times\vec{a})]=$$ $$(y-1)[(\vec{a}.\vec{a})\vec{b}-(\vec{a}.\vec{b})\vec{a}]+
z[(\vec{a}.\vec{a})\vec{c}-(\vec{a}.\vec{c})\vec{a}].$$
Similarly,
$$\vec{b} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{c})\times\vec{b}]=
(z-1)[(\vec{b}.\vec{b})\vec{c}-(\vec{b}.\vec{c})\vec{b}]+
x[(\vec{b}.\vec{b})\vec{a}-(\vec{b}.\vec{a})\vec{b}]$$ and
$$\vec{c} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{a})\times\vec{c}]=
(x-1)[(\vec{c}.\vec{c})\vec{a}-(\vec{c}.\vec{a})\vec{c}]+
y[(\vec{c}.\vec{c})\vec{b}-(\vec{c}.\vec{b})\vec{c}].$$
So
$$0=\vec{a} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{b})\times\vec{a}]+\vec{b} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{c})\times\vec{b}]+\vec{c} \times[(\vec{r}-\vec{a})\times\vec{c}]=$$
$$[-(y-1)(\vec{a}.\vec{b})-z(\vec{a}.\vec{c})+x(\vec{b}.\vec{b})+(x-1)(\vec{c}.\vec{c})]\vec{a}+$$
$$[(y-1)(\vec{a}.\vec{a})-(z-1)(\vec{b}.\vec{c})-x(\vec{b}.\vec{a})+y(\vec{c}.\vec{c})]\vec{b}+$$
$$[z(\vec{a}.\vec{a})+(z-1)(\vec{b}.\vec{b})-(x-1)(\vec{c}.\vec{a})-y(\vec{c}.\vec{b})]\vec{c}.$$
Since the vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are non coplanar, the coefficients at them are zeroes.
This provides a system of three linear equations for $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Thanks for the answer.......are you sure that there is no way other than solving that (slightly) daunting system of equations in $x,y,z$ using Cramer's rule, to obtain the final expression? Is there a way similar to that suggested by ancient mathematician to do this?

By the cyclicity of the initial equation we surely must have that $x=y=z$ which makes the solution easy? [But caution, I can't see why the solutions to the three equations are the same!]

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\lcontr{\mathbin\rfloor}
\newcommand\rcontr{\mathbin\lfloor}
$Here is an approach for (1) using geometric algebra that does not end with "and then solve this system of equations" and is basis independent.
To reduce clutter and typing I am going to write vector without arrows. let $I$ be the right-handed unite pseudoscalar. For any linear transformation $F : \R^3 \to \R^3$ we can find its inverse via the formula
$$
  F^{-1}(x) = \frac{I\bar F(I^{-1}x)}{\det F}.
$$
$\bar F$ is the (outermorphism of) the adjoint of $F$, defined by $F(x)\cdot y = x\cdot\bar F(y)$ for all vectors $x, y$. We rearrange (1) into the form
$$
  F(r) := a\times(r\times a) + b\times(r\times b) + c\times(r\times c) = a\times(b\times a) + b\times(c\times b) + c\times(a\times c).\quad
$$
To compute the adjoint of $F$, first we see using a triple product identity that
$$
  (x\times a)\cdot y = (a\times y)\cdot x
$$
so the adjoint of "right cross product" is "left cross product", and it follows that $\bar F = F$.
Because $I^{-1}x$ is a bivector when $x$ is a vector, we must compute the outermorphism of $F$ on bivectors. Unfortunately, the outermorphism of a sum is not necessarily the sum of outermorphisms, so we can't just consider each term in $F$ individually. Let $X = x_1\wedge x_2$ be a bivector blade and let $p,q$ be variables that range over $a,b,c$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
  F(X)
  &= F(x_1)\wedge F(x_2)
\\&= \sum_{p,q}[p\times(x_1\times p)]\wedge[q\times(x_2\times q)]
\\&= \sum_{p,q}[p^2x_1 - p\cdot x_1\,p]\wedge[q^2x_2 - q\cdot x_2\,q]
\\&= \sum_{p,q}\bigl[p^2q^2X + p\cdot x_1\,q\cdot x_2\,p\wedge q - p^2q\cdot x_2\,x_1\wedge q - q^2p\cdot x_1\,p\wedge x_2\bigr].
\end{aligned}$$
The RHS has to be antisymmetric in $x_1, x_2$, so we are free to antisymmetrize the second term and get
$$
  \frac12(p\cdot x_1\,q\cdot x_2\,p\wedge q - p\cdot x_2\,q\cdot x_1\,p\wedge q) = -\frac12(X\cdot p\wedge q)\,p\wedge q.
$$
For the last two terms, we are free to relabel $p,q$ to get
$$
  p^2q\cdot x_2\,x_1\wedge q + p^2q\cdot x_1\,q\wedge x_2
  = p^2(q\cdot x_2\,x_1 - q\cdot x_1\,x_2)\wedge q
  = p^2(X\rcontr q)\wedge q
  = \frac12p^2(q^2X - qXq).
$$
All together, letting $P = \sum_pp^2$ we have
$$
  F(X) = \frac12P^2X - \frac12\sum_{p,q}X\cdot p\wedge q\;\;p\wedge q + \frac12P\sum_qqXq.
$$
Now we may compute the adjugate of $F$ to be
$$\begin{aligned}
  F_{\mathrm{adj}}(x) := IF(I^{-1}x)
  &= \frac12I\left[P^2I^{-1}x - \sum_{p,q}(I^{-1}x)\cdot p\wedge q\:\:p\wedge q + P\sum_qqI^{-1}xq\right]
\\&= \frac12\left[P^2x - \sum_{p,q}x\wedge p\wedge q\:\:p\wedge q + P\sum_qqxq\right].
\end{aligned}$$
The last term we could write as
$$
  qxq = 2x\cdot q\,q - q^2 x,
$$
and the second term as
$$
  x\wedge p\wedge q\:\:p\wedge q = -x\cdot(p\times q)\:p\times q.
$$
This means that we know $r$ up to a scale factor:
$$
  (\det F)r = F_{\mathrm{adj}}(A) = P\sum_qA\cdot q\,q + \frac12\sum_{p,q}A\cdot(p\times q)\,p\times q,
$$$$
  A = a\times(b\times a) + b\times(c\times b) + c\times(a\times c).
$$
To calculate $\det F$, we note that $F_{\mathrm{adj}}(F(x)) = (\det F)x$, so in particular taking the vector derivative of this yields
$$
  \nabla F_{\mathrm{adj}}(F(x)) = (\det F)\nabla x = 3\det F.
$$
The chain rule tells us that
$$
  \nabla F_{\mathrm{adj}}(F(x)) = \bar F(\nabla)F_{\mathrm{adj}}(x) = F(\nabla)F_{\mathrm{adj}}(x).
$$
It will be best to put $F$ in the form
$$
  F(x) = \sum_qq\times(x\times q) = \frac12(Px - \sum_qqxq).
$$
The only geometric calculus identity we need is the following: for any constant vector $y$
$$
  \nabla x\cdot y = y.
$$
Now we see that
$$
  6\det F
  = \left(P\nabla - \frac12\sum_oo\nabla o\right)\!\left(P\sum_qx\cdot q\,q + \frac12\sum_{p,q}x\cdot(p\times q)\,p\times q\right)
  = P^3 + \frac12PQ_\times - \frac12P\sum_{o,q}oqoq - \frac14\sum_{o,p,q}o(p\times q)o(p\times q)
$$
with $Q_\times := \sum_{p,q}(p\times q)^2$. The above expression for $\det F$ must be a scalar, so we are free to take its scalar part; the scalar part of $oqoq$ is
$$
  (o\cdot q)^2 + (o\wedge q)^2 = 2(o\cdot q)^2 - o^2q^2
$$
and we have an analogous expression for $o(p\times q)o(p\times q)$. Letting $Q_\bullet = \sum_{p,q}(p\cdot q)^2$ and $Q_3 = \sum_{o,p,q}[o\cdot(p\times q)]^2$, we see
$$
  6\det F = P^3 + \frac12PQ_\times - PQ_\bullet + \frac12P^3 - \frac12Q_3 + \frac14PQ_\times.
$$
We can simplify a bit using $P^2 = Q_\bullet + Q_\times$; we could also expand $Q_3$ somewhat, but I will abstain from doing so. We finally have
$$
  \det F = \frac1{24}(9P^3 - 7PQ_\bullet + 2Q_3)
$$
and our final expression is
$$\bbox[border:1px solid black]{
  r = 12\frac{2P\sum_qA\cdot q\,q + \sum_{p,q}A\cdot(p\times q)\,p\times q}{9P^3 - 7PQ_\bullet + 2Q_3},
}$$$$
  A = a\times(b\times a) + b\times(c\times b) + c\times(a\times c),
$$$$
  P = \sum_pp^2,\quad Q_\bullet = \sum_{p,q}(p\cdot q)^2,\quad Q_3 = \sum_{o,p,q}[o\cdot(p\times q)]^2,
$$$$
  p,q = a,b,c.
$$
It's likely that the other two problems can be approached in a similar manner, but I have not tackled them yet.

Thank you for your answer @Nicholas ! But um I'm sorry I don't understand the bit about bivectors....I understand the part about the use of the adjoint and everything else but that bit is new to me.

@Cognoscenti So you are familiar with geometric algebra and are confused on one particular point, or are you not familiar with geometric algebra?

@Cognoscenti I thought of an efficient way to compute the determinant, so now my answer has a full expression for $r$.

I'm not familiar ):  but I do know the basics of the outer product

It seems that David Hestenes' site (geocalc.clas.asu.edu) isn't working anymore. Do you know where else I can read his works?

@mr_e_man The Wayback Machine seems to work, the latest archive is June 27th, 2023. There are also less legal avenues. I don't think I know of anything other than those options.

Huh. I thought I tried that already and the PDFs weren't available. Yes, it seems to work (with just one or two exceptions).

Oh, I must have found this instead.
